# cURL Request - how do I do it?

Tags: php, api, curl

Can somebody please point me in the right direction how I might use the following:

```
curl "https://api.xxxxxx.com/phones/:number/calls" \
-d"call[phone_number]=<number-to-call>" \
-d"token=<api_token>" \
--insecure
```

I have tried to find the answer, but I just cannot seem to get anything working for me - it should make a phone ring!!! in theory! But cannot find a way of sending the request with PHP.

Thanks,
B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this using PHP's [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(
  'call[phone_number]' => '<number-to-call>', 
  'token' => '<api_token>'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.xxxxxx.com/phones/:number/calls');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i always take too long to post lol yeah sorry :D

```
<?php     

    //optional comment out or delete    
    error_reporting(E_ALL);    

    // The POST URL and parameters    
    $request =  'http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/driver/'.$u.'/profile?output=xml';    

    // Get the curl session object    
    $session = curl_init($request);    

    // Set the POST options.     
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    

    // Do the POST and then close the session    
    $response = curl_exec($session);    
    curl_close($session);    

    // Get HTTP Status code from the response    
    $status_code = array();    
    preg_match('/\d\d\d/', $response, $status_code);    

    // Check for errors    
    switch( $status_code[0] ) {    
        case 200:    
            // Success    
            break;    
        case 503:    
            die('Service unavailable. An internal problem prevented us from returning data to you.');    
            break;    
        case 403:    
            die('Forbidden. You do not have permission to access this resource, or are over your rate limit.');    
            break;    
        case 400:    
            // You may want to fall through here and read the specific XML error    
            die('Bad request. The parameters passed to the service did not match as expected. The exact error is returned in the XML response.');    
            break;    
        default:    
            die('Your call returned an unexpected HTTP status of:' . $status_code[0]);    
    }    

    // Get the XML from the response, bypassing the header    
    if (!($xml = strstr($response, '<?xml'))) {    
        $xml = null;    
    }    

    // Output the XML    

    $worldDriverprofile = simplexml_load_string($xml);    

        $playername = $worldDriverprofile['name'];    
        $playerlevel = $worldDriverprofile['level'];    
        $playermessage = $worldDriverprofile['statusMessage'];      
        $playerimage = $worldDriverprofile['image'];
        $playerdefault = $worldDriverprofile['defaultPersona'];

    echo "Driver Name: $playername <br />";    
    echo "Level: $playerlevel <br />";     
    echo "Message: $playermessage <br />";
?>
```

this is for the SpeedAPI on need for speed world, but you can change it around for wahtever xml you are calling from.